# Python MatplotLib not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science

I know this post is probably a duplicate, but I have some issues of matplotlib not plotting anything and there are no errors in the python shell output. Nothing even pops up for a plt.show

I have tried a pip uninstall matplotlib and installed the latest matplotlib-2.02 .whl from lfd.uci.edu but I still have the same issues nothing plotting or errors in the shell. And I assume this is probably due to another python extension that matplotlib relies on....(?)

Can anyone send me some info how to troubleshoot? And also what is the matplotlib back end services? Im using python 3.6

Thank you

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\bbartling\\Documents\\Python\\test_SP data\\1st 

 GoRound\\testElectData.csv')

df = df[['kWhDay','CDDbase55']]
# print(df.head())

ys = df['kWhDay']
print(ys.head())
xs = df['CDDbase55']
print(xs.head())

def best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys):
    m = (((mean(xs) * mean(ys)) - mean(xs*ys)) /
         ((mean(xs)*mean(xs)) - mean(xs*xs)))
    b = mean(ys) - m*mean(xs)
    return m, b

m,b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)

print(m)

regression_line = [(m*x)+b for x in xs]

plt.scatter(xs,ys)
plt.plot(xs, regression_line)
plt.show
```

Comment: You really need to include some code that illustrates your problem. It's impossible to tell what the issue is currently.

Comment: Im an entry level python programmer, but here it is:

Comment: Not as a comment. As an edit. It will be illegible otherwise

Comment: I just added something  below as an answer to my own question, hopefully it worked/posted ok

Comment: No, now you've posted it as an answer. Please delete your answer and move the code to the question.

Comment: Also, `show` is a function so you need `plt.show()` with brackets to actually call it. The error is yours, nothing to do with matplotlib

Comment: If the "problem" is just that it shows nothing and ends immediately, the problem was identified by rogan; but you also mention "back end[s]", is there some error message you're getting? Include that, otherwise this is just a case of a typo.

Comment: That was totally the problem, no brackets (). Sorry! Can this post be deleted?